# Why won't Enzyme find my elements when the generated HTML looks find?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Given this React test code:

```
const A = props => <input { ...props } />;
const Component = () => (
   <A className="foo" />
);
const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);

console.log( wrapper.html(), wrapper.find('input').length );
```

The output is

```
<input class="foo"/> 0
```

and I don't understand why. Can someone explain how I can make `wrapper` find the `input` element given the given components?

---

**Note**: The relevant dependencies I currently have are :

```
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
"react": "^16.9.0",
```

Comment: Did you try `wrapper.find(input).length`?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati I found that comment suspicious, nonetheless ran it, and got the error I had expected to receive: `input is not defined`. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @YanickRochon Don't have any platform right now to run your test case. Just wanted to try without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example this input is second component level to be rendered. `shallow` renders only one component so your wrapper would have structure:
`<A className="foo" />`.

If you want to render this input you should use `mount()` or 
`const wrapper = shallow(<Component />).shallow()` to render 2 levels of components. In your case if you have complex structure with multiple levels of components I would go with `mount()`

```
const Component = () => (
   <A className="foo" />
);
const wrapper = mount(<Component />)

console.log( wrapper.html(), wrapper.find('input').length );
```

Comment: So, call `shallow` recursively? The example was very basic, because the actual code may have a variable number of nested components. I have never used Enzyme before.

Comment: So then you need to use `mount()` instead if you want to go to the last level of depth.